# LogicNP Software (www.ssware.com) - Support-Team not responding

Tags: .net-6.0, contacts, crypto-obfuscator

Our company is currently facing troubles with the "Crypto Obfuscator" by "LogicNP Software" ([www.ssware.com](http://www.ssware.com)) using it with .net 6.0 Code.

We have an active subscription, but nobody responds to our requests!
They mention the following promising line in their contact form:
"We respond within 1 business day, usually in less than 8 hours."

Does anybody else use this tool with .net 6.0?
Did anybody have contact with this company in the last months?

We already tried to contact them through the contact form and the mentioned e-mail adresses.

Comment: They did not respond to any message.
We now look for an alternative obfuscation software.
Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

They are frozen by covid events.
I believe they are no longer on the market
I'm using Babelfor.net and Reactor.net.
Both have a correct cost and the software is good.